# CMake qt5_add_translation, how to specify the output path?

Tags: cmake, qt-linguist

I use `qt5_add_translation` to run lrelease and generate the *.qm files*. By default the *.qm files* are put at the root level of the build dir, no matter where you put the *.ts files* in the source dir.

How can I specify a subdir for those files in the build ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a property on the *.ts files* before calling the Qt macro :

```
set_source_files_properties(${TS_FILES} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_LOCATION your_output_path)
```

Where `TS_FILES` contains the list of the *.ts files* and `your_output_path` is the path where to put the *.qm files* (relative to the build directory or absolute).

Because the macro will retrieve the property to make the path of the *.qm files* (tested with **Qt 5.9**) :

```
get_source_file_property(output_location ${_abs_FILE} OUTPUT_LOCATION)
if(output_location)
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${output_location}")
    set(qm "${output_location}/${qm}.qm")
else()
    set(qm "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${qm}.qm")
endif()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use manual call of lrelease and lupdate utilities

```
set(TS_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/translations")

set(TS_FILES
    "${TS_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}_ru_RU.ts"
)

find_program(LUPDATE_EXECUTABLE lupdate)
find_program(LRELEASE_EXECUTABLE lrelease)

foreach(_ts_file ${TS_FILES})

    execute_process(
        COMMAND ${LUPDATE_EXECUTABLE} -recursive ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} -ts ${_ts_file})
    execute_process(
        COMMAND ${LRELEASE_EXECUTABLE} ${_ts_file})

endforeach()
```